# How can I inform myself that an automatic SQL Server process has worked?

Tags: sql-server, import, process, automation

I have a Windows batch file which extracts some data from a remote system and then imports it into an instance of MS SQL Server 2014. The batch file runs SQLCMD and uses SQL files to bulk insert from the text files into a staging table, tidy the fields up and move the data to a production database.

Having finished the development of this, I would like to test the stability of the process by easily knowing when it has run successfully.

- I could check the batch file error log, but it is part of a larger process which means it takes a while to find the SQL Server part.
- I could send an email to myself when the process has finished, but this does not tell me if it worked **properly**. By this, I mean if the INSERT INTO statement from the staging table to the production table did not produce any errors.

Does anyone have any suggestions? My gut feeling is that I need to include something in the SQL statements I use to import the data. Thanks!

Comment: How do you measure "**properly**"? We have no idea. Also, this seems like a weird thing to alert on - imagine if the banks sent the police a message every hour saying "not getting robbed"? Your code should be built to determine its own success and to detect and handle errors - get an alert when it breaks, not when it works.

Comment: @Aaron: This is only temporary, as I would like to see when it has worked each day, so I can go in and analyst the data. You are quite right in that I should be getting an alert when the process hasn't worked, but I can surely use a similar approach to accomplish this.

Comment: Detecting errors is pretty easy using `TRY/CATCH`. Have you looked into error handling at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. count lines/records in your textfile
2. import
3. count records after import
4. if count1=count2 then continue
5. tidy up fields  (update blablabla set changefield='new' where myfield='badinfo')
6. test tidy up :  select count(*) from blablabla where myfield='badinfo' and changefield<>'new'
7. if testTidyUp-count = 0 then cleanup = correct ... continue
8. count records after tidy up
9. export to production
10. count records in production
11. if count3=count4 then ... let mysql know all is 'ok'

All the else ... mail that something is wrong

Comment: Surely using `TRY/CATCH` is more straightforward then all this counting work...